# how do I manually cleanup the last flyway migration that ran against a database

Tags: database, migration, flyway

I want to manually remove a flyway migration that has run successfully against the database.  It is the last migration that ran.

Will this work:

1. Manually revert the changes that were performed in the migration script (it added a column so will drop this column)
2. Remove the entry for the migration from the schema_version table

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work, but in addition you will need to remove the the offending migration script if you don't want it run again on the next `migrate`.

You could also leverage `repair` if you wanted to keep the migration around but make alterations to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you want to undo the changes done by a migration, you should create another migration script that will do so. This practice is recommended because it avoids modifying the DB state outside of flyway.